# JQuery '.css' not functioning properly on Firefox - works perfectly on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, browser

I have a sort of abstract art piece on the main page of my portfolio that moves about depending on where the mouse cursor is.

This animation works perfectly on Safari, Google Chrome and Opera.

The issue on Firefox is seems to be only when the middle block attempts to move down

Here's a link to my portfolio: http://benjaminthomasgibbs.co.uk/

Okay I know my css code is not properly formatted, I like it this way - could that be the problem:

JS:

```
// MIDDLE SLATE ANIMATION 


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slateMid').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#slateMid').css('top', '160vh');
       // LEFT SLATE
        $('#slate').css('height', '20vh');
        $('#slate').css('top', '45vh');
        $('#slate').css('left', '24vw');
        $('#slate').css('width', '46.5vw')
        $('#slate').css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px');
        $('#slate').css('background-color', '#FEBD45');
        // RIGHT SLATE
        $('#slateEnd').css('height', '23.5vh');
        $('#slateEnd').css('top', '19vh');
        $('#slateEnd').css('left', '24vw');
        $('#slateEnd').css('width', '46.5vw');
        $('#slateEnd').css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px');
        $('#slateEnd').css('background-color', '#DF4655');
    })
    $('#slateMid').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#slateMid').css('height', '68.5vh');
        $('#slateMid').css('top', '11vh');
        $('#slateMid').css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 10px #888888');
        $('#slateMid').css('border-left', '4px solid #000');
         $('#slateMid').css('border-right', '4px solid #000');
        // LEFT SLATE
        $('#slate').css('height', '34.5vh');
        $('#slate').css('top', '34vh');
        $('#slate').css('left', '26vw');
        $('#slate').css('width', '14vw');
        $('#slate').css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 10px #888888');
        $('#slate').css('background-color', '#DF4655');
        // RIGHT SLATE
        $('#slateEnd').css('height', '45.5vh');
        $('#slateEnd').css('top', '17vh');
        $('#slateEnd').css('left', '56vw');
        $('#slateEnd').css('width', '14vw');
        $('#slateEnd').css('box-shadow', '5px 5px 5px #888888');
        $('#slateEnd').css('background-color', '#FEBD45');
        $('#slateEnd').css('border-left', '4px solid #000');
    })
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="changeBottomLeft">
</div>
<div id="changeBottomRight">
</div>
<div id="slate">
</div>
<div id="slateMid">
</div>
<div id="slateEnd">
</div>
```

Comment: Side-note: pass object and call `.css()` method once i.e. `$('#slateEnd').css({ 'top': '17vh', 'left': '56vw'});`

Comment: Okay cool, I found my way easier to read - as it was getting quite confusing. Thanks for the tip though, much appreciated.

Comment: I agree with satpal that it would be beter to do it that way, but if you want to keep it in seperate functions you can also do `$('#slate').css('height', '20vh').css('top', '45vh').css('left', '24vw');` this will save you a lot of jquery objects and easier to edit later one. These functions can each be on a new line if you prefer of course.

Answer (score 1):

why do you not use animate() jquery function?

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Comment: I'm quite new to jquery tbh. Need to finish the courses really.

Comment: I have heard of that function though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completly sure if i understand you question, but i think this is your problem.

The middle slate behaves very shaky because the enter and leave events are fired way to often. This make the animation look strange and wonky, but it will also take a lot from the device to process it.

That is why you should use a debounce, more in this article if you are interested: [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

The code snippet below will make sure that your mouse enter / leave events won't be triggered more than once every 50 ms

```
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
$('#slateMid').on('mouseleave', debounce(function() {
        $('#slateMid').css('height', '68.5vh');
        $('#slateMid').css('top', '11vh');
        $('#slateMid').css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 10px #888888');
        $('#slateMid').css('border-left', '4px solid #000');
         $('#slateMid').css('border-right', '4px solid #000');
        // LEFT SLATE
        $('#slate').css('height', '34.5vh');
        $('#slate').css('top', '34vh');
        $('#slate').css('left', '26vw');
        $('#slate').css('width', '14vw');
        $('#slate').css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 10px #888888');
        $('#slate').css('background-color', '#DF4655');
        // RIGHT SLATE
        $('#slateEnd').css('height', '45.5vh');
        $('#slateEnd').css('top', '17vh');
        $('#slateEnd').css('left', '56vw');
        $('#slateEnd').css('width', '14vw');
        $('#slateEnd').css('box-shadow', '5px 5px 5px #888888');
        $('#slateEnd').css('background-color', '#FEBD45');
        $('#slateEnd').css('border-left', '4px solid #000');
    },50));

$('#slateMid').on('mouseenter', debounce(function() {
        $('#slateMid').css('top', '160vh');
       // LEFT SLATE
        $('#slate').css('height', '20vh');
        $('#slate').css('top', '45vh');
        $('#slate').css('left', '24vw');
        $('#slate').css('width', '46.5vw')
        $('#slate').css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px');
        $('#slate').css('background-color', '#FEBD45');
        // RIGHT SLATE
        $('#slateEnd').css('height', '23.5vh');
        $('#slateEnd').css('top', '19vh');
        $('#slateEnd').css('left', '24vw');
        $('#slateEnd').css('width', '46.5vw');
        $('#slateEnd').css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px');
        $('#slateEnd').css('background-color', '#DF4655');
    },50));
```

Comment: This provides some important information but the problem still persists on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation moves the middle element out of screen, that means the "mouseleave" callback is sort of automatically called by your animation.

For me, it seems that the behavior on Firefox is the normal one. Maybe Webkit based engines only evaluate **"mouse*"** events when cursor is moving.

To answer, i think you should divide screen in three parts to trigger animations.

here is a simple snippet to demonstrate this :

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('.animated').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass('slided');
  });
  
  $('.animated').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('slided');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.animated {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.animated.slided {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="animated"></div>
</div>
```